# C++ Private And Public Function

Tags: c++

I need to add an subtract values from the following program however I get the error when I reach the adding part, how can I still show it after adding as 'quarters, nickels, dimes and pennies' .

How come I get 8 when I get to the adding part? Please help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Purse
{
private:
    int quarters;
    int dimes;
    int nickels;
    int pennies;

public:
    void display_purse(int, int, int, int); 
    int insert_money(int, int, int, int);
    int remove_money(int,int,int,int);  
};

int main ()
{
    int qua, dim, nic, pen;
    int quaa, dimm, nicc, penn;
    int quaaa, dimmm, niccc, pennn;

    cout << "Enter the number of Quarters :" << endl;
    cin >> qua;

    cout << "Enter the number of Dimes :" << endl; 
    cin >> dim;

    cout << "Enter the number of Nickels :" << endl; 
    cin >> nic;

    cout << "Enter the number of Pennies :" << endl; 
    cin >> pen;


    Purse purse1;
    purse1.display_purse(qua, dim, nic, pen);

    cout << endl << "Current content of the purse:  " << qua << " quarters " << dim          <<      "    dimes " << nic << " nickels " << pen << " pennies " << endl << endl;

    cout << "or " << qua/4 + dim/10 + nic/20 + pen/100 << " dollars" << endl << endl;

    //starts adding

    cout << "Enter the number of Quarters to add : " << endl;
    cin >> quaa;

    cout << "Enter the number of Dimes to add : " << endl;
    cin >> dimm;

    cout << "Enter the number of Nickels to add : " << endl;
    cin >> nicc;

    cout << "Enter the number of Pennies to add : " << endl;
    cin >> penn;

    cout << endl << "The amount after entered is :" << purse1.insert_money(quaa,    dimm,      nicc ,penn ) << endl << endl;

//starts removing

    cout << "Enter the number of Quarters to remove : " << endl;
    cin >> quaaa;

    cout << "Enter the number of Dimes to remove : " << endl;
    cin >> dimmm;

    cout << "Enter the number of Nickels to remove : " << endl;
    cin >> niccc;

    cout << "Enter the number of Pennies to remove : " << endl;
    cin >> pennn;

    cout << endl << "The amount after entered is :" << purse1.remove_money(quaaa, dimmm, niccc, pennn) << endl;

    cout << "or " << quaaa/4 + dimmm/10 + nic/20 + pennn/100 << " dollars" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

void Purse::display_purse(int x, int y, int z, int a)
{
    quarters = x;
    dimes = y;
    nickels = z;
    pennies = a;
}

int Purse::insert_money(int quaa, int dimm, int nicc, int penn)
{
    quarters += quaa;
    return quarters;

    dimes += dimm;
    return dimes;

    nickels += nicc;
    return nickels;

    pennies += penn;
    return pennies;
}

int Purse::remove_money(int quaaa, int dimmm, int niccc, int pennn)
{
    quarters -= quaaa;
    return quarters;

    dimes -= dimmm;
    return dimes;

    nickels -= niccc;
    return nickels;

    pennies -= pennn;
    return pennies;
}
```

Comment: What do the four parameters "int, int, int, int" mean? That's just horrible.

Comment: You need some basic C++ lessons.  In this case, you have multiple `return` statements.  The code below the first return never executes.

Comment: You need to tell us what error exactly you receive.

Comment: Also, you don't need to have unique names for the input arguments to methods. They can be `insert_money(int quaa, int dimm, int nicc, int penn)` and `remove_money(int quaa, int dimm, int nicc, int penn)`

Answer (score 2):

You're dividing integers. For example `9/4 == 2` evaluates to `true` while `9/4 == 1.25` would evaluate to `false`.

The simple fix to your problem is to divide the number of each quantity of lesser coins by a floating point number instead:

```
cout << "or " << quaaa/4.0 + dimmm/10.0 + nic/20.0 + pennn/100.0 << " dollars" << endl << endl;
```

Additionally, your functions aren't actually completing their code.  As soon as you get to a return statement in a function it exits. For example:

```
int Purse::insert_money(int quaa, int dimm, int nicc, int penn)
{
    quarters += quaa;
    return quarters;  //Everything After this never executes

    dimes += dimm;
    return dimes;

    nickels += nicc;
    return nickels;

    pennies += penn;
    return pennies;
}
```

Should instead be:

```
void Purse::insert_money(int quaa, int dimm, int nicc, int penn)
{
    quarters += quaa;
    dimes += dimm;
    nickels += nicc;
    pennies += penn;
}
```

or Potentially:

```
void Purse::insert_money(int& quaa, int& dimm, int& nicc, int& penn)
{
    quarters += quaa;
    quaa = quarters;
    dimes += dimm;
    dimm = dimes;
    nickels += nicc;
    nicc = nickels;
    pennies += penn;
    penn = pennies;
}
```

If you'd like to return the total amounts of each type of currency in your purse

Finally display_purse, doesn't display the contents of your purse, it's actually just setting your purse to whatever values you pass in.

In general your posted code leads me to believe you haven't actually attempted to step through its execution and debug it yourself, but between my answer an other comments you should be on the right track to get started.